# Themeing Node/Add form - Taxonomy Field

Tags: drupal-6

I am theming a custom tpl.php file to style my forms.

I am printing my fields with something like this:

```
print drupal_render($form['field_sr_minutes'])
```

The problem is that on one element I need to get in this form is a taxonomy field, which is what i'm having a problem with. It will display with drupal_render($form), but I want to put it in a specific place, similarly to how I'm doing it with the normal node fields.

However, what I'm trying won't work:

```
Shows in HTML source as name="taxonomy[6]"
```

So, I'm trying things like

```
 print drupal_render($form['taxonomy[6]'])
 print drupal_render($form['taxonomy_6'])
 print drupal_render($form['name_of_taxonomy'])
```

But, no go...

Any Ideas???

Comment: How exactly are you printing it? Can you clarify? Have you tried printing simply taxonomy?

Comment: You are correct - just 'taxonomy' did it. I hadn't considered that, I guess becuse if there were multiple fields, I might want to put them in different places, but, I don't this time, so oh well! You wanna put that as an answer, so I can give you proper credit...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taxonomy fields are all present under the name `taxonomy` in the node form. So you can just print that.